# Unable to import shapely.geos

Tags: python-3.x, shapely

I installed shapely.

```
pip install Shapely
```

Installation log:

> Successfully installed Shapely-1.8.2

But I m getting below error while running:

```
import shapely.geos
```

E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shapely.geos'